# Illegal option -o pipefail

Tags: android-sdk, termux

I'm using termux and a git project to compile a git android apk source code the code is in bash command when i run the following command it says `illegal option -o pipefail`.[image: this is the output when i run the command]

Answer (score 1):

You're using the fast shell interpreter, `sh`, while apparently, as the file name suggests, that it's made for Bash. (In fact, `set -o pipefail` is a Bash-specific option).

To run that script properly, use `bash` as the "launcher":

```
bash buildOne.bash
```